# jQuery $.ajax function stops mid execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an attempt at a RESTful application but my $.ajax function stops in the middle of its execution.

```
function addEntry()
{
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: passAPI,
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataToJSON(),
    success: hideform
})
}

function hideform()
{
    $('#form').hide();
}
```

The data is put correctly in the database but the form doesn't get hidden. Anyone know why that happens ?

Comment: set up an Ajax error handler and see if it is being called. Look at the response with Fiddler/Charles/Firebug. I would guess invalid JSON being returned.

Comment: Everything seems fine, may be your form is not getting recognized, is  `$('#form')` is the correct id of your form ?

Comment: I'd recommend you to create an `error` callback to check if any error is being returned.

Comment: cross domain with no jsonp support?? that would stop it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried setting up an error statement that didn't return anything. When I tried again it worked.

I think I fixed some dumb syntax error.

Sorry !

Comment: If anyone encounters the same problem : the solution was to add "async:true" even if it's supposed to be on by default.

Answer (score 0):

Given there are no errors.  Does this work? I added the `function()`

```
function addEntry()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: passAPI,
        dataType: "json",
        data: dataToJSON(),
        success: function() {
            hideform();
        }
    })
}

function hideform()
{
    $('#form').hide();
}
```

Comment: Should make no difference; in the OP the function is passed in correctly.

Comment: i don't think this changes anything as `hideform` is also a function, but none of these functions have the `data` parameter.. could that be the issue?

Comment: Ah, I thought it could be something simple.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work either. I'm trying the error handler recommended by epascarello, I'll see what it says.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe: It doesn't matter.  The functions aren't using the parameter, so it doesn't need to be in the signature.  In JavaScript you can as many parameters as you want to a function

Answer (score 0):

making an assumption that your not using an event.preventDefault() if that's the case the ajax call will get cut off as the page reloads to submit the form using its default handlers.

if you already have an

```
event.preventDefault();
```

then ignore me ha.

Comment: I used a button instead and hooked on the click(), so no need for a preventDefault !